# Strings and text Input/Output

Tags: java

I am having trouble with writing this program (I'm probably way overthinking it!) Anyway, The problem I have is that I can do everything asked in one method... but I have to use the other five methods... could someone help me?!

Here are the directions I was give:

Write a Java program which will count and report the word and character count in a string. The program should also display occurrence of each alphabetical letter and percentage of the total represented. For this program, make the assumption that user will enter only lower case and uppercase alphabetical letters.

1. Your main method must have only variables declaration and calls to invoke methods
2. Your program must have at least 5 methods called stringLength,
   convertToUpperCaseString, wordCount, charCount, and
   OccurenceNPercentage.
3. Strings are immutable in JAVA, you will need a new array for convertToUpperCaseString.
4. The ASCII values for ‘ ‘, 'A', 'Z', 'a', and 'z' are 32, 65, 90, 97, and 122.

What I have:
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project_Strings_TextIO {

```
//initiate main method and call the rest of the methods used
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //call all methods


    }

//determine the length of the string
public static void stringLength(int length){

    //initiate scanner and prompt user for a string
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a string! --> ");
    String phrase = input.nextLine();

    //determine length of said string
    System.out.print("String length is " + phrase.length() + " characters long.");
}

//convert the string to uppercase
public static void convertToUpperCase(int uppercase){

    //upper case
    System.out.print("Look! I can uppercase your string: " + phrase.toUpperCase());

}

//count the words in the string
public int wordCount(String word){
    if(word == null){
        return 0;
    }
    String input = word.trim();
    int count = input.isEmpty() ? 0 : input.split("\\s+").length;
    return count;

    //use this? System.out.print("There are " + phrase.charAt(length) + " words in the string.");

}

//count the characters in the string
public static void charCount(int phrase){
    System.out.println(phrase.charAt(i));       
}

//count the occurrences and percentage of the characters in the string
public static int occurrenceNPercentage(int percent){
    int count = 0;

    //use percent for the loop???
    for(int i = 0; i < percent.length(); i++){
        if(percent.charAt(i) == char){
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you specify what is the problem? The directions indicate that it has to be done using 5 methods that are invoked from your main method.

Comment: im having a problem using the methods to do something that I know I can do an easier way (following directions is not my strong suit when I know a shortcut)

Comment: If you plan to do any significant amount of work with programming in the future, or even if you plan on taking just one more class, you should probably try a little harder to make use of the other methods. It may not appear to be the case here, but separating code into methods is a key part of making maintainable and easy-to-read code.

Comment: Yeah I understand that methods are super important, but my teacher did not do a good job of explaining them to us... hence asking the question. I'm trying to do the best I can off the little knowledge he told us and my use of google and this site....

Comment: Do you need the spaces are also counted? For example string "How are you" has 11 characters with the white spaces.

Comment: Also, what is the difference between charCount and stringLength. Its sounds same to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complete program that does what you need. However, it counts spaces as characters. Also, **stringLength()** and **charCount()** methods do the same thing - counting the characters. 
The percentage report method is taken from another answer on stack overflow. With this answer, you will learn nothing from your homework. Please at least try to understand the algorithms. Thanks and enjoy!

```
public class wordReport {

    //determine the length of the string
    public static void stringLength(String inputString) {

        //determine length of said string
        System.out.println("String length is " + inputString.length() + " characters long.");
    }

    //convert the string to uppercase
    public static void convertToUpperCase(String inputString) {

        //upper case
        System.out.println("Look! I can uppercase your string: " + inputString.toUpperCase());

    }

    //count the words in the string
    public static void wordCount(String inputString) {
        String[] wordsArray = inputString.split(" ");
        System.out.println("There are " + wordsArray.length + " words in the string.");

    }

    //count the characters in the string
    public static void charCount(String inputString) {

        System.out.println("There are " + inputString.length() + " characters in the string.");

    }

    //count the occurrences and percentage of the characters in the string
    public static void occurrenceNPercentage(String inputString) {
        char[] capital = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
            'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

        char[] small = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
            'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
        int[] count = new int[26];
        char[] chars = inputString.toCharArray();
        int myTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
                if (chars[i] == capital[j] || chars[i] == small[j]) {
                    count[j]++;
                    myTotal = myTotal + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Comlete count");
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + small[i]);
            System.out.print(" " + count[i]);
            if (count[i] > 0) {
                System.out.println(" " + (((float) count[i] / myTotal) * 100) + "%");
            } else {
                System.out.println(" 0%");
            }
            //calculate percentage for the full count
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter String");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputString = input.nextLine();
        stringLength(inputString);
        convertToUpperCase(inputString);
        wordCount(inputString);
        charCount(inputString);
        occurrenceNPercentage(inputString);

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks so much for the help! I realized that i was majorly overthinking it, and have all but the percentage part. your answer allows me to configure my own answer for that part. thanks for the help! :) (and I have learned... also realized that my teacher is really bad :/ )